# Cumulative distribution function of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ be two independent random variables, such that $\xi_1$ has a uniform distribution at $[-1,1]$ and $\xi_2$ takes values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the cumulative distribution function of $\xi_1 - \xi_2$?

Am I right that it has the form
$$F_{\xi_1-\xi_2}(t) = \begin{cases} 0, t\leq-2\\ \frac{t+2}{4},~t\in[-2,2]\\ 1,~t\geq2\end{cases} ~?$$

Comment: I think you are right.  It might help if you could give a one sentence explanation of why, though.

Comment: The condition in the first line of the cases should be $t \le -2$, otherwise looks fine to me.

Comment: Using PDFs instead of CDFs would be immensely more illuminating but yes, this is the CDF.